# Is it possible to stop this recursive function?

Tags: python, string, list, recursion

I wanted to implement the code by using recursive function **without for loop or while loop.**

And I wanted to implement function called go_through() and **take two parameters** as a list(list1) and an integer(letters) so that if the element of each length of string has **bigger or equal to integer**, I **replace** it **using the other function called replace_it()**

```
def go_through(list1, letters):


  get_list = list1[:]
  num =len(list1)
  index = 0

  if index != num:
    if len(get_list[0]) >= letters:
        get_list += replace_it(get_list[0])
        index += 1
        print(get_list, 'True')
        return go_through(get_list[1:], letters)
    else:
        get_list += [get_list[0]]
        index += 1
        print(get_list, 'False')
        return go_through(get_list[1:], letters)

  else:
    print(get_list)

def replace_it(string):
  if string == 'pineapple':
    return ['peach', 'and', 'pear']
  if string== 'delicious':
    return ['really', 'gross']

go_through(['pineapple','is','delicious','I', 'want', 'it'],7)
```

should be looking like

```
peach and pear is really gross I want it
```

**So I have a problem for this codes
It doesn't allow me to stop print as what I want to print is one line**

**The result** would be looking like the picture I attached
But I want to stop where I highlighted and return it as it is the same output what I wrote above.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I don't know if this is the main problem but `index` is always reset to 0 and the later increment of it is never used. Maybe instead add `index=0` to the parameters of `go_through` and place `index` in the recursive calls.

Answer (score 3):

The list is not reducing at any point. `get_list += [get_list[0]]` in the `else` block keeps the list the same size when followed by `return go_through(get_list[1:], letters)`, while `get_list += replace_it(get_list[0])` in the `if` will always extend the list.

Maybe you meant something like

```
else:
    # this isn't needed
    # get_list += [get_list[0]]
    return go_through(get_list[1:], letters)
```

Also, it seems that you're getting the list order mixed up in the first bit maybe.

```
if len(get_list[0]) >= letters:
    # this is adding the new list at the end, not replacing the word
    # get_list += replace_it(get_list[0])

    # you can send the shortened list to the function again,
    # and stick the replacement words at the start
    return replace_it(get_list[0]) + go_through(get_list[1:], letters)
```